# Application Pool slow to start with Google Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, iis-7.5, application-pool

this is one that is confusing me completely.

This issue doesn't happen with IE, Firefox, Safari ONLY with Google Chrome. (I haven't tested other browsers).

Basically I run my own web server, IIS 7.5, and have a number of development websites on it which will be published and used in production from the same server. As there are a number of websites I must use Dynamic Idle times for Application Pools as resources are restricted.

Usually this wouldn't be an issue and is the way to do things seemingly based on Microsoft's best practices however there seems to be a problem with Chrome loading pages once the application pool has timed out/gone idle.

Now I understand that it takes time for the application pool to restart, which they do within seconds and serve content not long after, but with Chrome the application pool takes close to a minute to start.

This doesn't happen on first load of the website however - it only happens with subsequent loads within the same browser/session.

As I said this does not happen with IE, Firefox or Safari, the other browsers I have tested, the application pool restarts almost immediately.

I had thought that maybe this was a server side issue but since the other browsers work fine I can only figure that it is Chrome at fault. Yet I still want to make sure it isn't actually a server side issue.

Any one have any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

I've just realized I posted this on Stack where it should be on Server Fault.

Sorry.

Anyway, something I wrote in the question prompted me to investigate further and I found this doesn't seem to be an application pool issue, although it could be, but more so a PHP-CGI issue. It might even be localized to my own machine.

Comment: Ok so this isn't localized. Through testing I have found that for some reason Chrome doesn't send, I can only imagine a signal, that other browsers do to flag a request to the WEB server. I have no better way to explain it. All the others respond immediately but Chrome takes 30-60s.